# Invoke applet method from angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, applet

I have to invoke an applet method from script code. I have include the applet this way:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Call Applet" onclick="arrancar();"/>
      <p>      
         <object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
               id="idApplet" width="0" height="0"
               codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,0,0">
               <param name="code" value="com.matchmind.clientesfd.applet.ClienteSFDApplet" />
               <param name="archive" value="./sfd_jar/appletSFD.jar" />
      <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4" />                         
         </object>                 
   </p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 
  function arrancar() {
   var applet = document.getElementById('idApplet');
      applet.iniciarCheckEstadoSimple();
      
   idApplet.arrancarServicio();

   console.log(document.applets.item(0).arrancarServicio());
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the file with Internet Explorer, applet is running, some messages appear for running it. In the method "arrancar" I try to invoke two applet's method in 3 differents ways but any of them work, there is an error that says the method doesn't exist. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: I'm doing a migration of an App and I have to invoke the applet in the same way. In that app they invoke the methods by the getElementById and when I execute that in Explorer I have no problem, but when I do the same in my app it doesn't work @AndrewThompson

Comment: What is 'my app'? Is it a angular application on Internet Explorer?

Comment: The old app, the one that works, it is a flex app, and the new one is an angular application tha we normally use in Chrome but for that funcionality, the applet, we run it on Explorer. I have realised that after I click the button run (before invoking function arrancar) there's a problem with the applet, it says "ClassFormatError Truncated class file", so I suposse that is the problem. Any idea? @zakki